# Headers/Footers/Pagination in HTML Doc Editor

Tags: asp.net, header, pagination, footer, ext.net

As part of our current project we are dropping MS Word in favour of an intranet-based document Editor; either one that we get off-the-shelf (tinyMCE/CKeditor) or we'll roll our own. We are using ASP.NET and Ext.NET (extjs) for development currently.

I'm trying to copy 3 features (IMO) Google Docs have nailed: pagination, headers and footers. Their implementation is an ideal setup.

Does anyone know if these are using CSS alone to generate the effects of paged documents? Or is there an underlying server-side tech. at play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS alone cannot handle pagination, you need server-side help for this.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected as much.